# How to mock ObjectMapper in xUnit?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

The project I am currently working on is full of tightly coupled code like this. As I am writing unit test code, I am struggling to mock them using moq in xunit.

```
var output = ObjectMapper.Map<ExpenseDetailOutput>(expenseDetail);
```

Is there any way to mock `ObjectMapper` without making the tested method loosely coupled?

Comment: The simple answer is: No.

Comment: Don't mock it. Mapper doesn't use external resources, not slowing down you tests, so test expected output without mocking mappers.